What are the risks of running an old Minecraft Server version?
I need to install Minecraft Server 1.19.2 on my VPS, but there are no download links to previous versions on the Minecraft website.
Looking for the server file needed, I've found this guide with links to official download pages captured by Internet Archive, and there, almost all versions can be found:

Previous versions can be found via Internet Archive (Java, Bedrock).

Now I'm wondering whether I can use a Minecraft server downloaded from the Internet Archive without any technical, security, or legal risks.

It's not an answer to your question, but I would like to point out that you can get old server .jars without using third party websites such as the Wayback machine. They are listed on the update page, like here for 1.19.2 as "Minecraft server jar"

I'd personally recommend at least looking into 3rd party servers as some of them have a longer official support timline and therefore may even be still within service life while serving minecraft 1.19.2. They also tend to be faster/better than the official servers


technical, security,

1.19.2 is fine as it's not really old as of writing. there are many such servers currently running this version without issue, though obviously you'll want to update to get the new features.
In general, the older the version, the higher the risks. older versions of minecraft may require you use older versions of Java that may or may not be vulnerable to exploits that go beyond "obtaining items you're not supposed to". The Log4J vulnerability from a few years back comes to mind, but it appears server downloads were patched retroactively to ensure even older versions would be safe. That being said, it's entirely possible that really old versions of minecraft server or java are vulnerable to something else entirely.

or legal risks.

if you're hosting a server among friends, not really. Be sure to use a whitelist, as someone random joining and griefing would be sad, but if you're not in a country with draconian laws regarding freedom of speech, I don't think there's many legal risks associated with simply hosting a minecraft server.

I'd be surprised if any Java update breaks a function Minecraft uses. I could be wrong, but I would expect newer versions of the JVM to be able to run the same code older versions could.

@Hearth weirdly, I believe some old versions (pre-1.16, so not relevant here) perform best on a Java 8 JVM. I'm not sure why.

If OP were using Internet Archive to get say, a 1.12 server, would the downloads still be patched retroactively for Log4J?

@Kaia that's definitely a possibility, though i'm assuming they're just using whatever is the latest snapshot that IA captured, so in that case it would be patched.

In addition to the previous answer, which seems accurate, even old server jars are probably okay for Minecraft. Many large, popular servers are running on frameworks based on 1.8.9 or even 1.7.10; there should be no issues with something like 1.19.2.

note that while yes, in practice, there are no public exploits for these versions, the big servers aren't actually running the versions and are just running a server that happens to talk the same version protocol as the older versions.
